# Golang. Get panic type

Tags: go, channel, panic

There's a code:

```
func (c *Connector) SendPacketFuture(p []byte) (future chan []byte) {
    defer func() {
        // TODO Check r to catch only chan panics
        if r := recover(); r != nil {
            future = nil
        }
    }()
    t := newConnectorTask(p)
    c.tasks <- t
    future = t.PacketFromServerChan
    return
}
```

`TODO` is pretty self-explanatory.
`c.tasks` is a channel and it can be closed by another goroutine. Since there's no safe way to send to channel that can be closed, I'm catching panics here. The problem is that different panics can occur and **I want to react to the one that is raised by writing to a closed chan**.

Is it possible to do this in Go?

Comment: In general, you shouldn't be trying to detect this, and there is another way to architect the program. There's a reason it's a panic meant to crash the program.

Comment: It's built around TTL cache. There's a rare race condition, when we try to create future on a connector, that has just expired and was removed from the cache. I can add SharedMutex to synchronize things, but this will only add constant runtime cost while solving a _potential_ RC. Dealing with panic seems a reasonable hack to me

Comment: But why is the channel being closed? A close is a signal that the sender (usually) sends, hence the panic when the channel is closed.

Comment: By closing I notify senders that the reference they are holding is no more relevant. I have this code In the end of the main connector function: `close(c.tasks);
 for t := range c.tasks {
  close(t.PacketFromServerChan);
 }`

Comment: Maybe there's a better solution, but don't know it

Comment: You usually would select on a separate channel to signal exit: https://play.golang.org/p/-2D4P70zm8

Comment: Oh, that's actually nice! Much better than my implementation. Thank you for idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recover message in this case is an unexported error value from the runtime, with the string value of `"send on closed channel"`.

The only thing you can do here is to match the error string:

```
if e, ok := r.(error); ok && w.Error() == "send on closed channel" {
    fmt.Println("recover from send on closed channel")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/LNcfdE9Bg2

In actuality, what you probably need is a separate channel to signal when to exit.

```
t := newConnectorTask(p)

select {
case <-c.close:
    // closing the c.close channel will unblock this case
    return
case c.tasks <- t:
}
```

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov: I should mention that though it's very unlikely to change, there's no guarantee that this continues to work in future versions of Go, nor that it works with other Go implementations, since the error value isn't specified.

Comment: What if I simulate this panic and then store an error type? It should be the same during the run, shouldn't it?

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov: should be, but there's still technically nothing preventing the runtime from adding dynamic information to that string. If you're going to do this, I would just define a constant string and fix it if it breaks.

Comment: @ViacheslavKroilov: the error's type isn't specific to this panic, it's currently called `plainError`